# CoffeeScript class-based controller for AngularJS doesn't update template

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Using AngularJS 1.1.5 with CoffeeScript I'm trying the use the new 'Controller as ...' syntax as follows:

```
class EventCtrl
    @$inject = ['$scope', '$http']

    constructor: (@$scope, @$http) ->
        @$http.get('/some/url/', config)
            .success (data) ->
                #set the events directive
                @events = data
            .error (data) ->
                console.log('error!')

app.controller('EventCtrl', EventCtrl)
```

With the following HTML fragment:

```
<div ng-controller="EventCtrl as ctrl">
    <div>{{ctrl.events}}</div>
</div>
```

This works alright except for the fact that changes in @events don't update (the binding point in) the template. The 'data' incoming in the `success` handler of the `@$http.get` is looking ok.

This code has been working with a previous version of AngularJS with the regular none-class controllers.

**UPDATE**
One (ugly) solution turns out to be explicity setting `this` (`@`) to a local value in the method (`thiz` in the example below). Not very elegant but it works.

```
class EventCtrl
    @$inject = ['$scope', '$http']

    constructor: (@$scope, @$http) ->
        thiz = @
        @$http.get('/some/url/', config)
            .success (data) ->
                #set the events directive
                thiz.events = data
            .error (data) ->
                console.log('error!')
```

**SOLUTION**
Use a fat arrow for the `success` handler. The constructor is automatically attached to the instance so a fat arrow is not needed there (it would have been if it weren't a constructor).

```
class EventCtrl
    @$inject = ['$scope', '$http']

    constructor: (@$scope, @$http) ->
        @$http.get('/some/url/', config)
            .success (data) =>
                #set the events directive
                @events = data
            .error (data) ->
                console.log('error!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to attach it to `scope`, not `@` (which might not even be your class instance, if `.success` changes the context. You can use coffeescript's fat arrow for that).

Also, what's the point of having an `init` method ? It's exactly the constructor's purpose.

Comment: Normally you would make it an instance attribute but it indeed seems that `@` inside the `http.get` is not the class but the window. A solution is to explicitely set `@` to the instance at the beginning of the method. Oh, and yes, you are indeed right that there is no need for the `init()`, it was a left-over because I stripped a lot of other code.

Comment: As I said, you can just use CoffeeScript's `=>` (fat arrow) to keep your `this`

Comment: You cannot use a fat arrow on a constructor (`cannot define a constructor as a bound function`), but using it on the `success` handler indeed solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I meant to use it on the success handler, indeed.